# Why does cap deploy cause problems but cap deploy:cold works fine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

I am in the process of uploading a website to a server.  I can successfully upload the site when i use `cap deploy:cold` and the site works fine.  However, i am planning ahead and want a means of updating the code on the website / running migrations on the db, without losing all the data in the database which seems to happen when i use `cap deploy:cold`.

My `deploy.rb` file contains:

```
require "bundler/capistrano"
#require "csv"

set :application, "my domain"
set :user, "my username"

set :repository, "."
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :deploy_to, "/home/users/#{user}/html/#{application}"
set :ssh_options, { :user => user, :port => 50022 }
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, :none

role :web, application
role :app, application
role :db, application, :primary => true

namespace :deploy do
task :start do ; end
task :stop do ; end
task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
    run "#{try_sudo} touch
    #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
end
end
```

This code is what i was advised to use by our hosting provider.  As i mentioned, `cap deploy:cold` works successfully and the site works as expected.  When I run `cap deploy` i get the error - `We're sorry, but something went wrong. We've been notified about this issue and we'll take a look at it shortly.`  I noted that the processes called by `cap deploy:cold` are `deploy:update`, `deploy:migrate` and `deploy:start`.  To try to narrow down the problem, i tried running `deploy:update` on its own, it works with no errors being reported but produces the same error message when i load the site.  Running `cap deploy:start` doesn't solve the problem.

Is anybody able to shed any light on what might be happening here?  Can you also confirm how I should go about uodating the website code & running database migrations in the future, without losing the data currently in the databases?
`

Comment: Further to my original post, if i run: cap deploy:update and then cap deploy:migrate the website starts performing...  Do you know why the cap deploy command doesn't work on its own?  Also, as per my post, how do i just update my site (either code or db migrations) without losing data from the databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you want one command to update your code and do all pending migrations. Luckily, `cap deploy:migrations` does just that. (not to be confused with `cap deploy:migrate` which only migrates.

If you want to run migrations while only using `cap deploy`, you could add:

```
before 'deploy:symlink', 'deploy:migrate' #use hook 'deploy:create_symlink' if using 2.10.0
```

To your recipe.

Comment: thanks for your answer and the comment about adding the code to the recipie was just what was confusing me...